# How to refresh a page on browser using selenium-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Follow the below part of the code:

```
driver.get "https://example.com/"

element = driver.find_element :name => "username"
element.send_keys "*****"
element = driver.find_element :name => "password"
element.send_keys "*****"
element.submit
```

Now point is when the `driver` opened the URL on the browser, Some times
the next page to which username and password has to be put by the
script, not coming- which causes the script to failed. Some intermediate
page is coming asking us to click on 'retry button' or 'refresh the
page'. Thus the script whenever such case occurred stopped execution, as
not getting the mentioned element.

So is there any way to refresh that intermediate page with "sleep"
before going to the "Log-in" page, so that script can run in one go?

Comment: `page.driver.browser.navigate.refresh` if using capybara

Comment: For capybara, I find 'visit current_path' works better.

Comment: As of 2022 using Capybara+Cuprite you'll want to use `page.driver.browser.reload`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the [`Navigation#refresh`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Navigation.html#refresh-instance_method) method:

```
driver.navigate.refresh
```

Comment: `navigate` gives you access to the navigation methods; similar to how you would do `driver.navigate.to`. Why not just `driver.refresh` - that's a question for the developers of the ruby bindings (ie it is just a preference on designing the api).

Comment: getting `undefined local variable or method `driver' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups...>`

Comment: I'm also getting undefined local variable or method `driver' - any ideas?

Comment: @RomanGaufman, `driver` is a `Selenium::WebDriver`instance. Are you sure that you have declared it with the same variable and/or have access to it in the particular method?

Comment: @RomanGaufman @mr.musicman In ruby using selenium the driver object is often stored in the variable `@browser`. This is the case if you are using PageObject for example.

Comment: your link is broken,  I just found this one for java https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Navigation.html. not sure where the ruby one is?

Comment: As of 2022 using Capybara and Cuprite you'll want this: `page.driver.browser.reload`

Answer (score 35):

For Capybara, I think [Tommyixi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509336/how-to-refresh-a-page-on-browser-using-selenium-webdriver/26667748#comment45829054_14509336) is the best:

```
visit current_path
```

Comment: It redirects me to the login page

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: Note that this will cause any query parameters in the URL to be lost on refresh. If that is an issue for you, I'd recommend using one of the other ways mentioned in this page.

Comment: This may work but its intent isn't as clear as `refresh`

Answer (score 26):

As mentioned in a comment by @Nakilon, with non-Poltergeist drivers in Capybara use the following to refresh the current page:

```
page.driver.browser.navigate.refresh
```

But for a universal fix, use:

```
page.evaluate_script 'window.location.reload()'
```

Answer (score 14):

For capybara, I recommend

```
page.evaluate_script("window.location.reload()")
```

This also works with poltergeist/phantomjs

Answer (score 6):

In cases like this, I've written some code to check for the existence of the input field.  If it doesn't exist, then refresh.

```
driver.refresh()
```

Comment: I do not believe this works for the ruby bindings (though it might work for some of the other bindings).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: my original answer assumed Capybara was being used.

You can just use `driver.get` on the page again to refresh.  There's no difference between clicking the refresh button in a browser and typing the same URL to load the page again, so `driver.get` is sufficient for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use - `driver.navigate().refresh();`.

Look here for example - http://reditblog.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-refresh-current-web-page.html

Comment: somebody else says it's `driver.navigate.refresh`. Your reference/link is not ruby, your link/ref and hence your example from there is maybe java or c#

Comment: that said, I notice that both `driver.navigate().to` and `driver.navigate.to` both work in ruby.